# Expected behavior when Clear-Site-Data header is set?

Tags: http, http-headers, browser-cache, cache-control, clear-site-data

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data):

> Clear-Site-Data header clears browsing data (cookies, storage, cache) associated with the requesting website

Now trying it, you can see in the screenshot (Firefox v76) that in the Response section, `Clear-Site-Data` was set in the browser, but, you can still see the assets as "cached":

Note: Even after navigating back/forth after some time, the cached assets doesn't seem to get cleared.

[image]

I'm under the impression this will happen instantly but I can't get it to work. Is this suppose to happen instantly or after some time, or I am just missing some else?

---

**Update for those who care:**

`Clear-Site-Data` appears to only work on `localhost` or `https`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this suppose to happen instantly or after some time, or I am just missing some else?

It is supposed to happen instantly. The (draft) [spec states](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-clear-site-data/#fetch-integration):

> If the `Clear-Site-Data` header is present in an HTTP response received from the network, then data MUST be cleared before rendering the response to the user.

Additionally, as you mention in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61737455/expected-behavior-when-clear-site-data-header-is-set/61775745#comment109308738_61775745) it is only supported when a request is secure (either `https` or `localhost`).

I prepared a simple test, with two resources:

- `index.html` -- a page that links to a CSS file, and also accepts a `?clear` query parameter to include a `CSD` header in the response
- `style.css` -- a CSS page with random colours, to make clear when it has been regenerated, that declares itself as cacheable

This behaved as specified with Firefox 76.0.1; on receiving a resource with `Clear-Site-Data: "cache"`, the cache is cleared before fetching its subresources.

#### Without `Clear-Site-Data`:

- Fetch `index.html` by entering the URL and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Repeat this. Note that the referenced `style.css` is served from the cache, and the page colour doesn't change

#### With `Clear-Site-Data`:

- Fetch `index.html?clear` by entering the URL and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Repeat this. Note that the referenced `style.css` is *not* served from the cache, and the page colour changes

#### Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import http.server
import socketserver

import random

PORT = 8000

class SampleDataHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        if ".css" in self.path:
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/css')
            self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=3600')
            self.end_headers()
            color = b"%06x" % random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF)
            self.wfile.write(b"html{background-color: " + color + b";}\n")
        else:
            self.send_response(200)
            if '?clear' in self.path:
                self.send_header('Clear-Site-Data', '"cache"')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(b"<link rel=stylesheet href=style.css>This is the content.\n")


httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), SampleDataHandler)

httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Could it be due to the `?clear` flag? because even without the `Clear-Site-Data` directive, any random `?string` should clear the cache at least on your first visit. What happens if you repeatedly visit with `?clear` flag? Also can you verify in the browser inspector if it's actually served from cache?

Comment: Yes, the network tab confirms that it's served from the cache when no `CSD` header is sent. Note that it's the `style.css` that is (or isn't) served from the cache, not the initial `index.html`.

Comment: I'm pretty much doing something similar (but in PHP). Mind if you send a screenshot of your browser inspector after visiting `index.html?clear` multiple times through a link that links `index.html` to itself? Note: hitting refresh appears to deliberately clear cache so it must come from a self link.

Comment: As I mention, I'm reloading by entering the URL and hitting Enter, which respects the cache, rather than following a link. The browser inspector just shows whether or not `style.css` was served from the cache, as described in those cases. If you're able to run Python, try that example.

Comment: I have finally found why I couldn't get it to work: `Clear-Site-Data` only works on `localhost` or `https`. I don't think this is "officially" documented. I've been testing it on a non-localhost Docker URL that's why it never worked. After testing on `localhost` I can verify `CSD` works instantly. Although I wasn't able to test your example, it still helped me in a way so I will accept it.

Comment: Good find! [This line](https://hg.mozilla.org/integration/mozilla-inbound/rev/015ed5271d5d#l6.202) appears to assert that in Firefox, and it's a no-op for a URI that's not considered "secure". It should probably be listed with [Features restricted to secure contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts/features_restricted_to_secure_contexts).